# Trouble sorting a linked list in ascending order (receive a segfault) using bubblesort in c

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am currently working on a project in my c programming course where we are suppose to take values from a text file and place them in a linked list. The structure has 2 lists, one in the order it was inputted shown as next and the second placed in ascending order shown as sort. I choose to do a bubble sort to put the values in ascending order. My structure for the linked list is shown below.

```
typedef struct NODE {
    int value;
    double key;
    struct NODE *next;
    struct NODE *sort;
}sortedList;
```

Part of what makes my bubbles sort work is found in the main. checkAscending will make sure the sort list is in ascending order and will return 1 if it is not. If i control the first node and make sure this value is the smallest the code will run perfectly otherwise its always the segfault

```
while ( checkAscending(headSort) == 1 ){

      bubbleSort(headSort);
}
```

The code for bubble sort is shown below and the problem is that it results in segmentation fault. I believe this is because when the linked list is at the first node the previous node doesn't exist.

```
void bubbleSort(sortedList *headSort ) { 
  sortedList *prev = headSort; 
  while(headSort != NULL && headSort->sort != NULL){ 
    if (headSort->key > headSort->sort->key){  
      /*swaps the two nodes*/
      sortedList *temp = headSort ;  
      prev->sort = headSort->sort ;
      headSort->sort = headSort->sort->sort;
      prev->sort->sort = temp;
    }
    prev = headSort; 
    headSort = headSort->sort; 
  } 
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this and was hoping someone could give me a clue as to what to try next to allow the first node to be sorted.

Comment: Please don't tag `c++` if you are writing `c`.

Comment: try to run it in the debugger and step through it

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  How do you create/initialize your nodes?  You should ensure that node pointers are always NULL until you allocate them on the heap.  When you remove a node, you should always ensure that any pointers to that node are NULL.  Never attempt to access a node through a NULL pointer.

Comment: You should pass pointer-to-pointer to your bubblesort function

Comment: So the goal is to walk the initial list and rearrange the `sort` links as you go?